# AddRule of RelativeLayout is not working

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I am trying to add a Relative layout programatically to a Linear layout. To that relative layout i am adding an imageview and a textview programatically. I have added rule to make the text view to the top of the imageview and bottom right. But addrule seems to be not working.Below is my code.

```
 RelativeLayout relLyt=new RelativeLayout(mContext);
                    TextView textView=new TextView(mContext);
                    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#59000000"));
                    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    textView.setTextSize(14f);
                    textView.setText("3:20");
                    textView.setPadding(15,10,15,10);

                    final ImageView myImage = new ImageView(mContext);
                    myImage.setTag(i);

                    //myImage.setOnClickListener(this);
                     myImage.setId(i);
                    myImage.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher));


                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

                    lp.height = height ;
                    lp.width = width/2 ;

                    lp.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);



                    myImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    myImage.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    relLyt.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    relLyt.addView(myImage);
                    relLyt.addView(textView);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)textView.getLayoutParams();
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT,myImage.getId());
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,myImage.getId());
                    params.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
                    textView.setLayoutParams(params);


                    contactViewHolder.img_lyt.addView(relLyt);
```

Comment: `myImage.setId(i);` - What is the value of `i` there?

Comment: flow is RelativeLayout rel = new RelativeLayout(Activity.this); LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(Activity.this); rel.addView(lin); Then create a new TextView or whatever you want, and add those views into the lin. sooo. lin.addView(textView); lin.addView(checkBox); etc

Comment: i value is 0 there

Comment: That's your problem. `0` means basically _false_ in `RelativeLayout` rules, which doesn't make sense for those particular rules - `ALIGN_RIGHT` and `ALIGN_BOTTOM` - so they're ignored. Reference `View`s have to have an ID of at least `1`. (Btw, if you comment with @username, the user will get notified of your comment. I'd've responded earlier, but I didn't know you'd replied to my question.)

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. Can you put it as asnwer, so that i can accept your solution

Comment: No problem. Actually, I've answered this same thing before, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate, when I get a chance later to find that post. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!